# How can I detect the number of fingers used in a swipe gesture?

Tags: windows-phone-8

My intention is to have different gesture-based actions occur depending on whether the user swipes the screen with one or two fingers. I'm a little new to touch app development and I'm not seeing the necessary information in either Manipulation events or the Toolkit GestureService. I'm fine with using more low-level touch logic or manually tracking the number of touch contacts if necessary, I just need a little guidance on how to differentiate single from double-touch in a gesture.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to resolve your problem. There is property to find the second touch point in the gesture panel.

```
GestureSample sample = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
Vector2 first = sample.Position;
Vector2 second = sample.Position2;
```

Position2 property will return the seocond touch position in the Gesture panel.